# Need expression not to match after a colon appear

Tags: python, regex

So I have a list of names and wanted to filter out the ones in proper format. For reference, the format I need is IP::hostname. This is the regex formula I currently have:

`^\d+(\.|\:)\d+\.\d+\.\d+::.+\w$`

However, I need to modify it so that if there are any colons (:) in or after the hostname, for it to not match the expression:

This matches which is correct:

`10.179.12.241::CALMGTVCSRM0210`

This matches but should not:

```
10.179.12.241::CALMGTVCSRM0210:as
```

Any help on how to modify my expression to not match any colons after the host name would be appreciated

Comment: Replace `.+` with `[^:]*`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/XM3lsr/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: A site that I use for regex testing my [regex expressions](https://regex101.com/). Really helpful for debugging what I need since it breaks down what all my expressions are representing

Comment: Why are you using `(\.|\:)`? Can there be a colon after the first digits?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Some entries have a : instead of a . so I have to account for both of them

Comment: Ok. So, you may replace all ``\.`` with `[.:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+` pattern matches 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and thus matches colons allowing them. You need a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), `[^:]*`, that will match 0+ chars other than a colon.

You may fix you regex (and enhance a bit) using

```
^\d+[.:]\d+\.\d+\.\d+::[^:]*\w$
                       ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XM3lsr/1)

To make sure you want to match a valid IP you'd rather use

```
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}::[^:]*\w$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XM3lsr/2) ([IP regex source](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)). The `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` matches a single octet from `0` to `255` and `(?:\.<octet_pattern>){3}` matches three repetitions of a dot and an octet pattern.